# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 4 into section 0, but there are only 4 rows in section 0 after the update'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, dictionary

Ok I've seen previous questions in obj C and tried them. What i'm trying to build is a Contacts app similar to iphone one. I'm having this problem in inserting row in my table. Earlier before I never had this problem with inserting rows I probably think it is because of my bad data structure?

The solution I tried was tableView.beginUpdates and endUpdates but still same error. Here's my code for contact list.

```
    class ContactsListViewController:  UITableViewController, AddContactViewControllerDelegate {

    let cellID = "contactCellID"
    var sectionNames = ["A","B","C","D"]
    var name = [0: ["Amber", "Ajay", "Abhishek", "Anshul"], 1: ["Borat", "Bruno", "Billooo"], 2: ["Chinku","Champu","Champak"], 3: ["Daya", "Divya","Delhi Police"]]

//    
//    @IBOutlet weak var addBarOutlet: UIBarButtonItem!
//    @IBAction func addBarButton(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
//        performSegueWithIdentifier("AddItemSegueID", sender: addBarOutlet)
//    }
//   

    //var nameSet = ["0": "Amber", "1": "Blah", "2": "Chris" ]
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return name.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let array = name[section]
        return (array!.count)
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellID, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let nameArray = name[indexPath.section]
//        guard let nameArray = name[indexPath.section] else {
//            print("Invalid ")
//            cell.textLabel?.text = "Not Found"
//            return cell
//        }

        cell.textLabel?.text = nameArray![indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        var Keys = [Int] (name.keys)
        Keys.sortInPlace()
        let value = Keys[section]
        var sec = ""
        if value == Keys[section] {
            sec = sectionNames[section]
        }
        return sec

    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "AddItemSegueID" {
           // let navcontroller = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
           // let controller = navcontroller.topViewController as! AddContactViewController
            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! AddContactViewController
            controller.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func addContactViewController(controller: AddContactViewController, didFinishAdding item: ContactNames) {

        //var dictKeys = [Int](name.keys)
        let newName = item.text
        let firstIndex = newName.startIndex
        //let firstChar = newName[firstIndex]
        var check = name[0]!

        let newRowIndex = check.count

        check.append(newName)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: newRowIndex, inSection: 0)
        let indexPaths = [indexPath]
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()

        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    func addContactViewControllerDidCancel(controller: AddContactViewController) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

---

---

ContactNames is normal swift class that coontains a string property.
The other thing is i implemented a protocol in AddItemVC in order to send data back to pervious view controller so i made a delegate which i also learnt recently. Heres yhe addItemVC:

```
 protocol AddContactViewControllerDelegate: class {

    func addContactViewControllerDidCancel(controller: AddContactViewController)
    func addContactViewController(controller: AddContactViewController, didFinishAdding item: ContactNames)
}

class AddContactViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


    weak var delegate: AddContactViewControllerDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var doneOutlet: UIBarButtonItem!

    var contactList = ContactsListViewController()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        nameField.becomeFirstResponder()
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
        doneOutlet.enabled = false
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        nameField.resignFirstResponder()

    }
    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let oldText: NSString = textField.text!
        let newText: NSString = oldText.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
        doneOutlet.enabled = (newText.length>0)
//        if newText.length > 0 {
//            doneOutlet.enabled = true
//        }else {
//            doneOutlet.enabled = false
//        }

        return true
    }

    @IBAction func saveAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let newItem = ContactNames()
        newItem.text = nameField.text!

        delegate?.addContactViewController(self, didFinishAdding: newItem)

    }
    @IBAction func cancelAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        delegate?.addContactViewControllerDidCancel(self)
    }
}
```

Also if you suggest a better data structure for this.

Comment: Solution for me: ' controller.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)' replace with dismissviewcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native collection types in Swift are value types that means the objects are always copied when you get a value for a key or for an index.

You assign the array for key "0" to variable `check` and append a value

```
var check = name[0]!
...
check.append(newName)
```

but that does **not** change the original array in dictionary `name`.
You need to assign the array back to the dictionary

```
name[0] = check
```

Isn't it more convenient to use the actual letters for the keys rather than unrelated numbers?

Comment: Found it: Tried that too wasnt working same error. During debugging dismissviewcontroller wasnt get call dont know tried controller.dismiss... . The solution was navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true). Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Between beginUpdates and endUpdates, you need to update your data source so that it matches the operations like insertRowsAtIndexPaths. So if you had four rows, and insert one as you do, your data source must also be changed to now have five rows. Exactly as the error message says.

Comment: Actually `begin/endUpdates` has no effect at all in this case (single insert action) and can be omitted. It's only mandatory to update the data source array **before** calling `insertRowsAt...`

Comment: okay how do i update the data source then? Did you mean my dictionary? This method I found for updating dictionary. 'updateValue(forKey:)' But even this how can i do it dynamically?  I came up with this more method 'tableView.reloadData()' which gives same error